# Table RowCount in a Common Table Expression (CTE) query?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I am trying to get a record count in my output... but struggling with the syntax. Can't see what I'm doing wrong.... help please

```
SELECT 
    InfoSchema.table_catalog + '.' + 
    InfoSchema.Table_Schema + '.' +
    InfoSchema.Table_Name as PhysicalName,
    CONVERT(char(10), SysObj.crdate,126) as Created,
    SysInx.rows Records
    
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS InfoSchema left join
    SYSOBJECTS AS SysObj ON InfoSchema.TABLE_NAME = SysObj.name

WHERE 
    TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
    AND SysObj.crdate is not null
    AND SysObj.id = (
                        SELECT MIN(SysInx.id), rows
                        FROM SYSINDEXES AS SysInx
                        WHERE SysInx.id = SysObj.id
                    )
```

The desired output would be this:

```
PhysicalName     Created      RowCount
--------------+------------+-------------
tableName1      2020-01-01    127653
tableName2      2018-01-01    234098
tableName3      2019-01-01    0
```

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results - what you are trying to achieve is not obvious from your query.

Comment: I don't see a CTE here. Is your question missing some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery in the result column.

```sql
SELECT 
    ...
    (
       SELECT MAX(rows)
         FROM SYSINDEXES AS SysInx
        WHERE SysInx.id = SysObj.id
    ) AS Records
    
FROM 
    ...

WHERE 
    ...
    AND SysObj.id IN (
                        SELECT SysInx.id
                        FROM SYSINDEXES AS SysInx
                     )
```